# SQL value not available anymore

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite for a query as you see below. Therefore I need the average of the all the interactions. Including the "thankful" interaction as well, I don't get results (n/a) because it doesn't exist anymore since October 2022. What do I have to include into the code, that I don't get this error?

```
SELECT
  SUBSTR(facebookOwnPosts.time, 1, 7) AS month,
  ROUND (
     AVG (
      likes + love + wow + haha + sad + angry + comments + shares + thankful
    )
  ) AS enagegementperpost
FROM
  facebookOwnPosts
GROUP BY
  month
```

I believed that if there is no data for one of the parameters it would just leave it out.

Comment: "if there is no data for one of the parameters it would just leave it out" - no, SQL doesn't work like that. In it, `NULL` is contagious. If you add it to anything, the result is also `NULL`. I think you want to use `COALESCE` here.

Comment: What is a *"thankful" interaction*? Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas: this must be referring to the different reactions one now can do instead of a simple "like".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes exactly. It was one of the reactions on Facebook. It is not available anymore, this is why I ran into that problem. So since October there is no more data for it. I guess it should work with COALESCE to use the data until October and from then on having 0 as the value.